# Issue with node-notifier module

Tags: node-notifier

I'm working on a NodeJS/Electron/Angular app and I am using the node-notifier module. Every things work correctly but at the bottom of my notification message I have an inappropriate "toast" string.
It only happens when I use the "icon" property.
What should I do to remove that string ?
Thanks in advance.

```
const notifier = SystemJS._nodeRequire('node-notifier');
notifier.notify({
title: 'Example of a notification',
message: 'Message of the notification',
icon: `${APP_ROOTDIR}/shared/assets/images/new-notification-icon.png`,
timout: 5}, () => { });
```

PS : My operating system is Windows 10 and this is a screenshot of the notification : [image: Screenshot of the notification]

Comment: can you post your complete code include declaration of 'notifier'?. The "toast"  string is the default appID of notifier. Refer 'snoretoast' module issues for further info about customizing appID here: https://github.com/mikaelbr/node-notifier/issues/154 . You can use this command to customize the appID along  with message, title and icon of the notifier

"SnoreToast.exe -p C:\Projects\testSnoreToast\coulson.png -m Hello -t World -s Notification.Default -appID Wow-wow"
 if you could post your complete code, that would be helpful to figure out the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I edited my post and I added the declaration of the notifier. Is it enough ? I don't think adding anything more would be useful.

Comment: I try to add  `appId: ' '` in the notify properties as it's indicated in your link but the 'toast' string still appears.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code and let me if this works out for you, it worked fine for me. The default timeout period is 5 seconds.

```
const notifier = require('node-notifier');
notifier.notify({
    'title': 'My notification',
    'message': 'Hello, there!',
    'icon': '/home/xxx/Desktop/icon.jpg'
});
```

Here's the output:

[image]

Comment: Hello,I don't know why but the error just came from my computer. On my collegue computer it worked fine without this string. I really don't understand why but it doesn't matter anymore. However, thank you very much for your time.

Comment: You're welcome @Lolo. Have a look at the "Notifications & Actions" in Settings of windows 10 and explore them, that might help.